# Find the minimum number of tanks to hold the maximum quantity of wines, at each tank maximum possible capacity

Tags: excel, algorithm, math, optimization

My business is in the wine reselling business, and we have this problem I've been trying to solve. We have 50 - 70 types of wine to be stored at any time, and around 500 tanks of various capacity. Each tank can only hold 1 type of wine. My job is to determine the minimum number of tanks to hold the maximum number of type of wines, each filled as close to its maximum capacity as possible, i.e 100l of wine should not be stored in a 200l tank if 2 tanks of 60l and 40l also exist.

I've been doing the job by hand in excel and want to try to automate the process, but using macros and array formulas quickly get out of hand. I can write a simple program in C and Swift, but stuck at finding a general algorithm. And pointer on where I can start is much appreciated. A full solution and I will send you a bottle ;)

Edit: for clarification, I do know how many types of wine I have and their total quantity, i.e Pinot at 700l, Merlot 2000l, etc. These change every week. The tanks however have many different capacities (40, 60, 80, 100, 200 liters etc) and change at irregular interval since they have to be taken out for cleaning and replaced. Simply using 70 tanks to hold 70 types is not possible.

Also, total quantity of wine never matches total tanks' capacity, and I need to use the minimum number of tanks to hold the maximum amount of wine. In case of insufficient capacity the amount of wine left over must be smallest possible (they'll spoil quickly). If there is left-over, the amount left over of each type must be proportional to their quantity.

A simplified example of the problem is this:

```
Wine: 
----------
Merlot 100 
Pinot 120 
Tocai 230 
Chardonay 400

Total: 850L

Tanks: 
----------
T1 10 
T2 20
T3 60 
T4 150 
T5 80 
T6 80 
T7 90 
T8 80 
T9 50 
T10 110 
T11 50 
T12 50

Total: 830L
```

Comment: You need to specify all the input you have. You don't mention if you know beforehand how much of each wine type you need to store but I assume you have some information about that as well? Otherwise, use 70 tanks to store 70 different types of wine.

Comment: Ah yes, I do know how many types of wine I have and their total quantity, i.e Pinot at 700l, Merlot 2000l, etc. These change every week. The tanks however have many different capacities (40, 60, 80, 100, 200 liters etc) and  change at irregular interval since they have to be taken out for cleaning and replaced. Simply using 70 tanks to hold 70 types is not possible.

Comment: You should edit the question to hold all the information you have.

Comment: Ask the question on Mathematics Stack Exchange. It is a very simple linear optimization problem and you can solve it using the Excel Solver, or another program. Probably simpler than you think. Cheers!

Comment: Must you store all of each type? For your example, if you have `Pinot 700l, Merlot 2000l` and capacities of tanks `40, 60, 80, 100, 200`, obviously you cannot store everything you have. So how would you like it split? Evenly, proportional, all Pinot, all Merlot? You need to give us something that clearly makes one option better than another.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: IVLad: Ideally proportional quantity of each, thanks for the question, I forgot that important bit :)

Comment: @DavidGM: This problem is a generalisation of (i.e. at least as hard as) Knapsack, which is NP-hard.  Linear programming is a poly-time problem, so either your formulation requires an exponential number of variables and/or constraints, or you meant *integer* linear optimisation (which is as easy as LP to formulate but much harder to solve), or you have proved P = NP ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This greedy-DP  algorithm attempts to perform a proportional split: for example, if you have `700l Pinot, 2000l Merlot` and tank capacities `40, 60, 80, 100, 200`, that means a total capacity of `480`.

```
700 / (700 + 2000) = 0.26
2000 / (700 + 2000) = 0.74

0.26 * 480 = 125
0.74 * 480 = 355
```

So we will attempt to store `125l` of the Pinot and `355l` of the Merlot, to make the storage proportional to the amounts we have.

Obviously this isn't fully possible, because you cannot mix wines, but we should be able to get close enough.

To store the Pinot, the closest would be to use tanks `1 (40l)` and `3 (80l)`, then use the rest for the Merlot.

This can be implemented as a [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem:

```
d[i] = true if we can make sum i and false otherwise
d[0] = true, false otherwise
sum_of_tanks = 0
for each tank i:
  sum_of_tanks += tank_capacities[i]
  for s = sum_of_tanks down to tank_capacities[i]
    d[s] = d[s] OR d[s - tank_capacities[i]]
```

Compute the proportions then run this for each type of wine you have (removing the tanks already chosen, which you can find by using the `d` array, I can detail if you want). Look around `d[computed_proportion]` to find the closest sum possible to achieve for each wine type.

This should be fast enough for a few hundred tanks, which I'm guessing don't have capacities larger than a few thousands.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you often have tanks that have the same volume as combinations of other tanks (e.g., if you have 50L, 30L and 20L tanks), then when tracing back through the DP matrix, there will often be more than one possible predecessor tank.  In this case you should always choose the *largest* -- since that leaves the option of using just some subset of the smaller tanks available for future wines.

Comment: The problem itself is not as hard as I thought, but it's extremely slow to solve. I tried brute forcing by looking for every combinations of tanks for 1 type of wine, then with each combination working down other types. Written in vba excel becomes unresponsive  at 20 types and 50 tanks.

Comment: @Van you don't need to brute force, you can use the DP algorithm I posted.